# (103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function

Tags: expresso-store, error, performance

Currently trying to work out why our ExpressionEngine install is running so slowley, have just checked our error log and it's full of the following:

```
(103)Software caused connection abort: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request function
```

The entire site seems to hang on every page load then once it gets past this hang loads fairly quickly.

What would cause this error and how can I go about fixing it? Any ideas?

We're running on ExpressionEngine 2.7 and are using the Expresso Store module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there are particular reason you are using mod_fcgi? Are you managing the server yourself?

From googling the error it doesn't seem related to EE at all - this question on Stack Overflow may be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477627/mod-fcgid-ap-pass-brigade-failed-in-handle-request-function

Comment: Thanks Adrian, unfortunately we don't manage the server, sounds like our server isn't powerful enough or we're simply doing too many requests then?

Comment: It does sound like a strange setup. Is it just standard shared hosting? You might be best to just email your host and ask them to take a look into the error.

Comment: It was MediaTemple's hosting, we moved and it seemed to fix the issue.